# Como criar objeto array javascript dentro de um FOR?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Preciso passar um objeto array da seguinte forma, para a api:

```
[paulo = 1, gustavo = 2, amanda = 3,...]
```

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$scope.salvarHabilidades = function(pro){

    var valores = pro.filter(function(o,i){
        return o.habilidades == true;
    });

    var habi = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){
        console.log(valores[i]);
        habi = [(valores[i].descricao = valores[i].idhabilidade)];
    }
    habi.idusuario = $rootScope.idPro;
    console.log(habi);

}
```

Pois o que aparece no console da linha "console.log(valores[i])" é isso:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a tela de seleção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `[paulo = 1, gustavo = 2, amanda = 3,...]` não é um array válido, cada indice vai ficar com o valor da atribuição. Não ficou claro pra mim o formato que precisa..

Comment: O @LucasCosta tem razão. Essa: [paulo = 1, gustavo = 2, amanda = 3,...] não é uma notação de objeto e muito menos de array. o Mais perto que você poderia chegar de uma notação de array seria: ["paulo = 1", "gustavo = 2", "amanda = 3",...]. Mas que com certeza não é o que você quer!

Comment: Preciso que o número esteja atribuido ao nome.
Pode ser que o exemplo que dei não seja um array válido, mas preciso montar de uma forma que seja. Entenderam?

Comment: Que seja ["paulo" = 1, "Gustavo" = 2, ...]

Comment: Uma estrutura legal seria [ {"nome": "paulo", "valor": 1}] pra mim

Comment: Poderia esclarecer um pouco a sua dúvida, Gustavo? por exemplo: O que são os valores numéricos? IDs de habilidades? Caso positivo, poderia uma pessoa possuir 2 ou mais?

Comment: Sim, isso @LucasCosta!
Os valores numéricos são os ids dos nome, exemplo, id do paulo, id do gustavo e assim por diante.

Comment: @GustavoSevero E qual seria o relacionamento com habilidades?

Comment: No lugar dos nome vão habilidades, @OnoSendai.

Answer (score 2):

Poderia armazenar objetos em array usando [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var habi = [];
var valores = [{
  "idhabilidade": 1,
  "descricao": "Descricao 1"
}, {
  "idhabilidade": 2,
  "descricao": "Descricao 2"
}]

habi = valores.map(function(item) {
  return {
    "nome": item.descricao,
    "valor": item.idhabilidade
  }
})

console.log(habi);
```

Comment: Em partes, deu certo, MAS, eu selecionei 3 habilidades e apareceu apenas 1 no console.
Preciso inserir mais dados nesse objeto, conforme vai rodando o FOR, entende?

Comment: Essa parte está alem da que você apresentou na pergunta @GustavoSevero

Comment: O que mais preciso informar? Na pergunta, título, coloque que era dentro de um FOR, tanto que o FOR está no código.

Comment: *selecionei 3 habilidades e apareceu apenas 1 no console*, selecionou onde?

Comment: Desculpe, acabei de colocar na descrição da dúvida, Lucas.

Comment: Selecionei de uma tela com uma lista de checkboxs.

Comment: Alguma ideia Lucas?